# Sql Where statement dynamic with case

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a Stored Procedure where I pass a value of 0,1,2.
0= no where
1= Duration >0
2= Duration =0

> select * from Table where case  when @duration =1 then Duration else 1
>   end >0

this works however i can't get the other values to work. I've tried 3 case statements but only the last one works.

How can I get a dynamic where statement to work for 3 values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't use a `case` statement.  Just use boolean logic

```
select *
  from table
 where (@duration = 0)
    or (@duration = 1 and duration > 0)
    or (@duration = 2 and duration = 0)
```

Comment: Do note that this will cause a table scan if there are no other filtering/joining clauses. See other answers for alternatives using ad-hoc SQL.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming I'm ready your question correctly, this should do the trick:

```
SELECT * FROM yourTable
WHERE (@whereType <> 1 OR Duration > 0)
AND   (@whereType <> 2 OR Duration = 0)
```

but be careful with this sort of construct if there table contains any significant number of rows: you will be forcing a table scan of `yourTable` unless you have other filtering clauses for which there are usable indexes.

**Edit:** Some will find Justin's answer clearer to read (the two acheive the same result), though I prefer to keep the `OR` clauses inside the brackets as I find the logic easier to follow especially when other filtering clauses are added. In either case the warning about index use and scanning holds.

**For Large Tables**

Neither this or the other arrangement is suitable for large tables (as your comments suggests you have noticed) unless there are other filtering clauses that dramatically limit the amount of rows the dynamic filter acts upon.

Within a stored procedure you have the option of ad-hoc SQL via `EXEC`:

```
SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM yourTable '
IF @whereType = 1 THEN @SQL = @SQL + 'WHERE Duration > 0'
IF @whereType = 2 THEN @SQL = @SQL + 'WHERE Duration = 0'
EXEC (@SQL)
```

Be *very* careful with this pattern. You can easily open yourself to injection attacks (though this example doesn't) with ad-hoc SQL.

See the article mentioned in Andy's answer for a very detailed discussion of the options available and the issues (with regard to performance, maintainability, and security) you might encounter with each. Erland's other articles are very useful, thorough, and well written too, see http://www.sommarskog.se/index.html (the first one, regarding dynamic SQL, is relevant here too).

Comment: the table is very large, over 100gb per day. using this and the blow example is not allowing the results to come back. any other options?

Answer (score 0):

See the article "Dynamic Search Conditions in T‑SQL" from Erland Sommarskog at http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html

This explains in detail your options for dynamic searching and the performance implications of doing so.